# Ubuntu 16.04 Node.JS app can't connect to MySQL database - Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, connection, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to launch my Node.JS application on an Ubuntu virtual machine. The application uses MySQL. When I run the app, I get the following error regarding what I'd assume is MySQL.

```
events.js:182
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED myIP:3306
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1041:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1064:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1153:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/root/pub code test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:145:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/root/pub code test/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:52:23)
    at Connection.connect (/root/pub code test/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/pub code test/runTest.js:17:12)
    at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:609:10)
```

Here's my code for connecting to MySQL:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection ({
  host: "myIP",
  user: "root",
  password: "password",
  database: "dbname"
});

connection.connect()
```

I've replaced the password, database, and hostname for security purposes, but I have indeed double checked all of them, along with the username

> Node.JS version: 8.4.0
>   NPM version: 5.3.0
>   MySQL version: 5.4.2
>   Ubuntu: 16.04

I'm not sure what I did wrong to get this error but if anyone knows why, please do let me know. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Got it! My simple fix was to change the IP to `localhost`. I was previously using just a standard public IP.